# why return statement in function will cause the bash script end

Tags: bash

when I run the follow bash script, it will never print "bye!".
It seems that return statement in dummy function will cause the bash script end, leave the left script not excute.

```
#!/bin/bash -ex

dummy () {
    if [ $1 -eq 0 ] ; then 
        return 0
    else
        return 55
    fi  
}

dummy 0
echo "when input 0, dummy will return $?"

dummy 50
echo "when input 50, dummy will return $?"

echo "bye!"
```

output:

```
+ dummy 0
+ '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
+ return 0
+ echo 'when input 0, dummy will return 0'
when input 0, dummy will return 0
+ dummy 50
+ '[' 50 -eq 0 ']'
+ return 55
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your she-bang line: #!/bin/bash -ex

That -e option tells bash to exit immediately after a command returns a non-zero value.

In this case it's the [ $1 -eq 0 ] when $1 is 55 so your script exits immediately.

Try run you script like this:

```
$ bash yourscript.sh
```

vs.:

```
$ bash -e yourscript.sh
```

Comment: I couldn't find the -e option in gnu bash manual. You don't happen to have a link to a reference where I can read/learn about it?

Comment: @Qsp It's in the bash manual, "buried" deep among the options. Run this in your bash shell to see the relevant paragraphs: man  bash|col -b|grep -A3 'OPTIONS'; man bash|col -b|grep -A 2 -- '-e *Exit'

Comment: @holygeek what's means of "--" in command "man bash|col -b|grep -A 2 -- '-e *Exit'"

Comment: @Leon -- tells grep that everything that comes after it are not to be treated as command line switches anymore. They are arguments. Without it grep would treat that '-e *Exit' as another switch. The use of -- is supported by programs that use the getopt library for processing command line switches and arguments.

Comment: I assume the -ex is the same as `set -e; set-x` which is documented here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Modifying-Shell-Behavior

Answer (score 0):

change

```
#!/bin/bash -ex
```

to:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

and it will work.

Actually you can do it with `#!/bin/bash -x` also.

You meant to accomplish something else with the -e option?

Answer (score -2):

Use single quotes around 'bye!'. With double quotes the "!" causes a problem.

Comment: At the prompt, exclamations are problematic even in single quotes, but in a script file, they're not.  At the prompt, the exclamation mark is used by the csh-like history substitution mechanism (die, csh! die, history substitution mechanism from csh!)